# height of the window portview in a session variable

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

I would like to save the height of the window's portview (browser) in a session variable. Is that possible and how is it done?

var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();

Comment: if it is just for that javascript file , you can use global variables also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a PHP session variable?  You could make an AJAX call to a PHP script that would store the incoming variable in the PHP session.

Javascript

```
var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
jQuery.post('URL_TO_PHP_SCRIPT_HERE', {height: viewportHeight});
```

PHP

```
$_SESSION['viewportHeight'] = $_POST['height'];
```

Be sure to sanitize the incoming $_POST data. Maybe use `intval()` on `$_POST['height']`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

- Pass your variable in query string
- Pass it via hidden field
- Use **cookies** instead.
- Pass your variable via ajax and store in php session